# How can I compile bytecoin sources in Visual studio 2017 community edition

Tags: c++, cmake, cryptography

My OS is windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits, language setting is not English. When I follow the instructions for building bytecoin codes in Visual Studio on the URL https://github.com/bcndev/bytecoin . I can do everything without error till the part

> .... Now launch Visual Studio, in File menu select Open Folder, select .....

When I select "Open Folder" in the menu to open the folder "E:\bcndev\bytecoin" VS works for a while and displays two errors in CmakeLists.txt file. The first one is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       CMake Error at E:\bcndev\bytecoin\CMakeLists.txt:134 (add_library):
>     Cannot find source file:
>
> ```
> ../sqlite/sqlite3.c
> ```
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
>     .hpp .hxx .in .txx    bytecoin    E:\bcndev\bytecoin\CMakeLists.txt   134

and the second one is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       CMake Error at E:\bcndev\bytecoin\CMakeLists.txt:134 (add_library):
>     No SOURCES given to target: bytecoin-core bytecoin    E:\bcndev\bytecoin\CMakeLists.txt   134

Line 134 of CmakeLists.txt file is:

> ```
> add_library(bytecoin-core ${SOURCE_FILES})
> ```

How can I fix this errror and continue compiling these sources?

Comment: The first error is because `USE_SQLITE` option is in effect. Default value for option depends on whether your system is 64-bit (`OFF`) or 32-bit (`ON`). Because `Visual Studio x64 command prompt`, noted in README, implies 64-bit, it looks like you didn't follow that.

Comment: You are right I didn't choose 64 bits Debug project setting.

Answer (score -1):

I selected x64 Debug project setting. The error disappeared. Turns out I hedn't done the necessary steps for 32 bits explained on the URL [Github bytecoin compile guide](https://github.com/bcndev/bytecoin). Because of that I can only use 64 bits Debug project setting.